# Autodesk Forge Viewer - How do I fire an event after model loading is complete?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do I fire an event after model loading is complete?

I created the "basicSetting" function below.

```
function basicSetting(){
    viewer.setLightPreset(1);
    viewer.setQualityLevel(false, false);
    viewer.setGhosting(true);
    viewer.setGroundShadow(false);
    viewer.setGroundReflection(false);
    viewer.setEnvMapBackground(false);
    viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true);
}
```

And I applied it to the "onDocumentLoadSuccess" function.

But it didn't work.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` as per [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#geometry-loaded-event]) link and use it like this after you have initialised a viewer.

In typescript (using forge-typings)

```js
this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, (x) => 
{ 
    basicSetting();
}
```

Or if you wanna be extra save and make sure the function is never called elsewhere, just remove it and place its contents in the event callback.

```js
this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, (x) => 
{ 
    this.viewer.setLightPreset(1);
    this.viewer.setQualityLevel(false, false);
    this.viewer.setGhosting(true);
    this.viewer.setGroundShadow(false);
    this.viewer.setGroundReflection(false);
    this.viewer.setEnvMapBackground(false);
    this.viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true);
}
```

Not sure in which languages you are developing but it should be pretty simular !

Comment: Your answer was very helpful to me!
And, as you said, I removed the function.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` is a good choice - that event is triggered after *all* the geometry is loaded. If you wanted to run your configuration logic earlier, you could also consider `Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT` - this event is triggered when the viewer loads the initial model manifest (before loading its geometries).

Comment: @PetrBroz "Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT" This is better for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise waiting for viewer loading finish like as:

```
var loadedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var listener = function (event) {
    baseViewer.removeEventListener(
        Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, 
            listener
        );
        resolve();
}
baseViewer.addEventListener(
    Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
    listener
);
```

});
await loadedPromise;

Answer (score 0):

You can do the basic settings in `Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT` here as well.

```
viewer.addEventListener(
      Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT,
      function (event) {
        console.log("TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT ")
        loadBasicData()
      }
    )
```